# Inequality for 0-1-matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, inverse

Given a $n \times n$ matrix $A$ with entries 0 or 1 and non-zero determinant.

> Question 1: Is true that the sum of the entries of the inverse of $A$ is less than or equal to $n$?
>
> Question 2: Is true that the sum of the entries of the inverse of $A$ is less than or equal to $n$ in case $A$ has determinant $\pm 1$ and only the entries 1 on the diagonal? Is in this case the value $n$ uniquely attained by the identity matrix as this sum?

Both questions have a positive answer for $n \leq 4$. It would also be nice when someone with a good program/computer could gheck it for n=5 or even n=6.

Comment: "Both questions have a positive answer for n≤4"
.

Comment: @user247327 what do you mean with that quote?

Comment: "Both questions have a positive answer for n≤4"
That's clearly  NOT true for the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1\end{bmatrix}$ a 2 by 2 matrix of 1s and 0s with determinant 1 sum of entries 3> 2.  Did you mean that the sum of entries is less than or equal to $n^2$?  (Why can comments only be edited for 5 seconds?)

Comment: @user247327 sum of entries of the inverse of that matrix (not the matrix itself)!

Comment: It isn't easy to prove.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't work my friend. Consider a few thousand random $10\times 10$ matrices and you can get  $\sum_{i,j}A^{-1}_{i,j}\geq 16$.

EDIT. If I understand correctly your second point, you consider $0-1$ matrices with diagonal $1,\cdots, 1$ and $\det(A)=\pm 1$.

With  a random test, I find the following $10\times 10$ matrix $A$ with $\det(A)=1$ and $\sum_{i,j}A^{-1}_{i,j}=21$.

[image]

Comment: Well, I would think that too, but maybe the second question is positive. Or do you have a concrete counterexample?

Comment: Can you give a concrete example for that?

Comment: Thanks. Do you also have such an example where the sum of all entries of the inverse is larger than the sum of all entries of the original matrix? See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/342871/inequality-for-0-1-matrices .